# Include log4j in Ant Java task

Tags: java, ant, log4j

My project is as given below.

```
properties
lib
   a.jar
   b.jar
   c.jar
   d.jar
   log4j.jar
build.xml
```

I have a java task which references a jar in the lib folder. It writes the output as per the config in log4j properties.
Now where do i place the log4j.properties & mention it in ant java task.

This is how i run the java task & include jars for my project.

```
<path id="proj.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="some-task">
   <java classname="my.class.main" 
        classpathref="proj.classpath">
             <arg value="some args"/>   
   </java>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your java class, include this in the main method. Pass the file path of the log4j.properties

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[0]);
```

Something like this

```
<java classname="my.class.main" 
    classpathref="proj.classpath">
         <arg value="log4j.properties path"/>   
         <arg value="some args"/>   
</java>
```